# Java application run as root

Tags: linux, sudo

I'm testing Linux server where Java web application is run as root, I typed:

`>ps aux`

in the result I see:

`root     18265  (...)  Sl+  19:52   0:37 java -Xmx2g -jar test_app.jar`

what is the best explanation for admins to convince them to run application not as root?
What if user is not root, but in sudo group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there is an exploit in that program that allows for remote code execution, I as an attacker could trigger that vulnerability to run code as the root user. If I can take actions on behalf of `root`, I own the machine. I can do whatever I want on that device. I can view, modify or delete any file I choose. Any connections that machine has to other applications, I can leverage to then move laterally across the network. The `root` user is the highest privilege level, and should be protected for this reason.

If that java app is instead run as the user `user`, and `user` has sudo permissions, that would still be much more secure than running the app as root. In this case, if I were to exploit a vulnerability that allowed for RCE, I would only have the permissions and access that `user` has. I wouldn't be able to run sudo to escalate to root without the password for `user`, the hash of which is hidden away in `/etc/shadow` (a file that only root can read). So after the initial foothold on the linux machine, I would have to find a privilege escalation vulnerability to exploit in order to get root privileges. This adds a layer of security which helps to prevent high impact compromises.

Comment: Very good answer, note that sometimes it is not only by a security flaw but for example a java program having a console to execute shell script (e.g. apache-servicemix / karaf) in that case any operator can execute a shell script with root access without need to "hack" the program.